# Float to string general format

Tags: python

Python keeps using fixed format for large floats:

```
>>> str(1.0e-2)
'0.01'
>>> str(1.0e+2)
'100.0'
>>> str(1.0e-10)
'1e-10'
>>> str(1.0e+10)
'10000000000.0'
```

How can I make it print `1e+10` in the last case, similar to c++:

```
std::cout << 1.0e-2 << '\n'
          << 1.0e+2 << '\n'
          << 1.0e-10 << '\n'
          << 1.0e+10 << '\n';

0.01
100
1e-10
1e+10
```

I don't want to always use scientific notation.

How do I make Python conversion behave similar to C++ general format for

```
str(x)
```

when `x` is a float?

Comment: `"%.2e" % 1e-10`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with scientific notation

```
"{:e}".format(1.0e-7)
```

Or you can choose how many digits  to show after the decimal by adding `.n` before the `e`

```
"{:.2e}".format(1.0e-7)
```

Comment: I don't want to always use scientific notation: it will print `'1.000000e+02'` instead of `100`. Float comes in a variable and it may be `100.0` or `1e+10`. How do I make it behave like C++ example?

Comment: I think the C++ `std::to_string` function isn't specified so exactly; just choose a bound (say, 1e9) and write something like `('{:e}' if abs(x) >= 1e9 else '{}').format(number)`.

Comment: @user2052436 See my other example in my post where you can set the precision of the representation. But if you want to have a custom precision for when to use scientific notation you could just use if conditions for when to format with scientific notation or not.